# C++ template metaprogramming nested switch statement

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Let's assume I have an union type (variant type) like this one (simplified just for demonstration purposes)

```
enum class Type : uint32_t
{
  Unknown = 0,
  Int64 = 1,
  UInt64 = 2,
  Double = 3
};

struct Value
{
  Type dtype;
  union
  {
    int64_t i;
    uint64_t u;
    double d;
  };
}
```

And I intend to dispatch this value to different functions like this (actually function objects, but simplifying again...),

```
template<typename... T> auto eval(const T&... t)
{
   // ...
}
```

which takes a parameters pack, or simpler ones like:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> auto sum(const T1& a, const T2& b)
{
   return a+b;
}
```

In general I need a switch statement with the following structure:

```
  switch (o1.dtype)
  {
    case Type::Int64:
      switch (o2.dtype)
      {
        case Type::Int64:
          F(o1.i, o2.i);
        case Type::Double:
          F(o2.i, o2.d);
        //...
      }
      break;
    case Type::Double
      //...
```

for the case of invoking a functor with 2 parameters. But it gets much worse for the case of 3 parameters...

Is there any way to generalize it via metaprogramming? Ideally I would have only one switch statement, and all the nested ones generated.

Comment: You've simplified the example too much. e.g. what is `Type`? Please make a [mre].

Comment: Right about now, you're probably going to find `std::variant` and `std::visit` kind of handy. Doesn't make your problem entirely disappear, but at least provides a mechanism for implementing your code a bit more cleanly (and probably without an actual case statement).

Comment: This just happens to be exactly what `std::visit` will do with a `std::variant`. The shown code is, basically, reinventing the `std::variant` wheel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about `std::visit`, I cannot use `std::variant`, but perhaps having a look at the implementation of `std::visit` would give me the hints I need on how to implement this.

Comment: `std::visit` is based on how variadic template parameters work, on which `std::variant` is based on. `std::visit`'s implementation will not help you, much, unless you are also using a template with variadic parameters, to form your union. And if you do that you might as well use `std::variant`.

Comment: Do you plan to provide 9 overloads of `F()` for three types, two parameters? And 27 overloads for three parameters?

Comment: F() may not need 27 overloads, depending on functor (which me be also templated), one may be enough.

Comment: Why can't you use `std::variant`? To reiterate, this is just reinventing `std::variant`.

Comment: @sapito, probably some context would help the readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a variadic templated function that does the `switch` on the first argument and calls itself with the rest and a lambda that saves the first argument's type:

```
template<typename F, typename... T>
// decltype(auto) is used to deduce the return type from F, throughout
decltype(auto) apply_func(F f, const Value& v, T&&... vs) { // can't say "any number of arguments, all Values", so say "any arguments of any type" and just convert them to Value later
    switch (v.dtype) {
    case Type::Int64: // bind first argument of f to chosen variant of v, then apply new function (with one less argument) to remaining Values
        return apply_func(
            [&](const auto&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
                return f(v.i, args...);
            }, std::forward<T>(vs)...
        );
    case Type::UInt64:
        return apply_func(
            [&](const auto&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
                return f(v.u, args...);
            }, std::forward<T>(vs)...
        );
    case Type::Double:
        return apply_func(
            [&](const auto&... args) -> decltype(auto) {
                return f(v.d, args...);
            }, std::forward<T>(vs)...
        );
    default: throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown dtype");
    }
}

// final overload, when all arguments have been switched on and the chosen variants have been saved into f
template<typename F>
decltype(auto) apply_func(F f) {
    return f();
}
```

[Godbolt demo](https://godbolt.org/z/sM876v)

Comment: Thanks! Very close to what I want to implement. I can base my solution on this.